# Decrease font size by 1pt for all fields for crystal reports 13

Tags: crystal-reports

We are using VS 2008 with Crystal reports 10.5.When the report is run font size is decreased by 1pt for all fields by default (Don't know what is the reason for it).
Now we are upgrading to VS 2015 and SAP Crystal reports 13.0. When the report is run, now the font size is displayed correctly.

How to reduce font size for each field like in crystal report 10.5